# Blow up points on real projective plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

**What is the genus of the blow-up at $3$ non-colinear points of $\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^2$?** This question occurred to me as I was trying to eliminate the sigular points at the vertices of a given triangle when performing the isogonal conjugate. I hope this change of background surface would not ruin too many features of conics and cubics with respect to the triangle.

Comment: Degree is embedding-dependent, and you don't have one. Topologically, blowups are given by connect-summing in a projective space of the appropriate dimension. But this is frequently not really the right thing to think about from the algebro-geometric perspective. Can you provide a little more information about what you're trying to do?

Comment: @KReiser I think I am asking the genus.

Comment: @KReiser How about requiring the embedding to be degree and dimension minimal?

Comment: $\operatorname{Bl}_CM$ blowing up a codimension-$r$ nonsingular real subvariety $C\subset M$ with trivial normal bundle is diffeomorphic to $M\#(C\times\mathbb{RP}^r)$.  So you are left with $(\mathbb{RP}^2)^{\#4}$ which I will leave you to identify the genus.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks! That results in genus $4$.